# Content no fan to content fan

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I would like to change the content of my page, when the user clicks on a like button (it's directly reloading the page with the new content).

I can do that but only if I click on the log-in button first to get the basic information of my account. I don't want to require this step.

An exemple of what I want is at https://www.facebook.com/Dior (tab Dior VIII).

Answer (score 0):

There is a method named `getSignedRequest()`. Call this method. This method returns if the current user is already a fan of the Facebook page or not:

```
 $faceboook->getSignedRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will needs to implement a routine using one of the SDKs. Facebook passes a so-called signed request to all canvas apps and such running in an iframe. Among other things it includes the information if the current user has liked the page. You need to retrieve the information and check the like status.

For PHP this would be something like this:

```
<?php
require(facebook.php); // include Facebook PHP SDK

$app_id = "your_app_id";
$app_secret = "your_app_secret";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

if($signed_request = $this->parsePageSignedRequest()) {
  if($signed_request->page->liked) {
    // output fan content
  } else {
    // output non-fan content
  }
}

function parsePageSignedRequest() {
  if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
    $encoded_sig = null;
    $payload = null;
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
    return $data;
  }
  return false;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way of doing this using [FB.Event.Subscribe and edge.create](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/). The JavaScript code is in `http://fivespot.me/like-reveal-simple.txt`.

Add this to your landing page, change the application ID and the link you want to redirect to after the user likes where it says `yoursite.com/afterlike.html`.

This is the simplest most effective way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

A page gets a signed request. Decode this to find out if the user has like the page. In PHP:

```
<?php
    $signedRequestObject = parse_signed_request( $_POST["signed_request"],YOUR_APPLICATION_SECRET );

    if ($signedRequestObject["page"]){
        // This means this signed_request was generated on a page.
        if ($signedRequestObject["page"]["liked"]){
            // the page was liked
        }
    }

    //Used functions
    function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
        $sig = $this->base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode($this->base64_url_decode($payload), true);
        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            echo  'Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256 : ';
            return false;
        }
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            echo = 'Bad Signed JSON signature!';
            return false;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }
?>
```